# How to render XML error messages separately in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I'm creating a simple XML API in Rails, and currently, when there's an error, it renders the standard HTML error pages in `public/`, e.g. error in `/tests.xml` causes rendering of  `public/404.html`.

Is there a way to make it render `public/404.xml` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to take advantage of the fact that the `render` method can render custom XML and an HTTP status, like so:

```
# Renders '<error>Not found</error>'
render :xml => { :error => 'Not found' }, :status => 404
```